# Why does my HiLo game allow guesses outside of the 0-10 range?

Tags: java

I have a quick question about this HiLo game that I have been trying to fix from a while now. When I run the program it counts guesses outside of the 0-10 range, but I don't want it to do that. How do I fix that? Here is my code.

```
import java.util.Random; // Random number generator class
import java.util.Scanner; // reads user inputs

public class HiLo 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        // declare variables
        final int MAX = 10;
        int answer, guess;
        int numberOfTries = 0;
        String again;

        Scanner Keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

        do 
        {
            System.out.print(" I'm thinking of a number between 0 and "
            + MAX + ". Guess what it is: ");
            guess = Keyboard.nextInt();
            // guess
            Random generator = new Random(); // Random number generator. 0 to 10.
            answer = generator.nextInt(MAX) + 1;

            if (guess > 10) // if guess is bigger than 10 then error message
            {
                System.out.println("ERROR – Your guess is out of the range 0 to 10.");
            }
            if (guess < 0) // if guess is smaller than 0 then error message
            {
                System.out.println("ERROR – Your guess is out of the range 0 to 10.");
            }

            while (guess != answer) // If guess is not the answer
            {

                if (guess > answer) // If guess is more than the answer
                {
                    System.out.println("You guessed too high! \nTry again:");
                    guess = Keyboard.nextInt();
                }

                if (guess < answer)// If guess is less than the answer
                {
                    System.out.println("Too Low! \nTry again:");
                    guess = Keyboard.nextInt();
                }

                numberOfTries = numberOfTries + 1;

            }// end of the loop

            // display result
            if (guess == answer)
            {
                numberOfTries += 1;
                System.out.println("YOU WIN!");
                System.out.println("It took you " + numberOfTries + " tries!");
                System.out.println();
                System.out.print("Do you want to play again(Y/N)?");
            }

            Keyboard.nextLine(); // skip over enter key
            again = Keyboard.nextLine();

            numberOfTries = 0;

        } while (again.equalsIgnoreCase("Y"));

    } // end of class

} // end of main
```

Comment: You <0 >10 checks are not in the loop, so they'll only be done once...

Comment: Don't increment the number of tries when the guess is outside of the range? Did you write the code yourself and cannot guess it? Formatting the code properly would also help to understand logic a little bit.

Comment: @John3136 They are in a `do while` loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You report the error but you don't `continue;` (and use a logical `||`) like this

```
if (guess < 0 || guess > 10) {
  System.out.println ("ERROR – Your guess is out of the range 0 to 10.");
  again = "Y"; // <-- make sure we'll re-evaluate.
  continue; // <-- Add then skip the rest of the loop body
}
```